# maximum bound for edges in graph `G` if we want shortest cycle stay at `k`.

Tags: graph-theory, boundary-value-problem

In a simple graph G, what is the maximum bound for edges if we want shortest cycle stay at k.

How we can find this bound for a graph? Have it any formula or technique to calculate it?

thanks in advance

Comment: Assuming $k$ divides $n$, you could construct a ring of size $n$ and then insert hoops of lengths up to $n/k$. I don't know if it is tight, but it does feel like a worst case.

Comment: [Case $k=4$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420905/prove-simple-graph-with-conditions-on-vertices-and-edges-contains-triangle)

Comment: Look also parts of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571823/maximum-edges-in-a-square-free-graph) thread related to girth.